# how to access first key from a map having list of values as object in coffee script

Tags: json, coffeescript, yaml

I am accessing this yaml file (converted to json) using a rest call.

```
A:
  B:
    C: [ value1, value2, value3 ]
    D: [ value4, value5, value6 ]
```

looking at the json object on the uri, I see it being displayed like

```
{"C":["value1","value2","value3"],"D":["value4","value5","value6"]}
```

This result is expected, the way I am traversing the yaml file and sending it.

However, when I try to access the first key "C" of the map (yamlmap) using coffee script:

```
alphabet= (key for key,value of yamlmap)
```

It is not displaying anything. Is this the right way ?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KL29u/ What is different between that fiddle and your code? The `C` and `D` keys are a couple levels down but you should still get something.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not see any result in the link you provided. I do not see any difference. What result did it display? I will look into it. As far as I know, I am following the same approach.

Comment: Open your JavaScript console and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

As @mu-is-too-short have commented, your code is 'almost' right.
But I'd recommend below.

```
alphabet = Object.keys yamlmap
```

Furthermore explanation would be easily understandable by trying web compiler on http://coffeescript.org and comparing result of it.

In short,

```
alphabet = (key for key of yamlmap)
```

which would be better than your code `(key for key,value of yamlmap)` which is getting-and-ignoring value of the object, is still going to be equivalent in js this big below

```
alphabet = (function(){
  var results = [];
  for (key in yamlmap)
    results.push(key)
  return results;
})();
```

While the code I recommend would be almost the same in js like below and about 2 to 3 times faster than above.

```
alphabet = Object.keys(yamlmap);
```

Many template languages can have this kind of problem and we should be aware on that.